# Python Beginner: How to delete a dictionary inside a list which is also inside another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have following json file:

```
    [{
    "subject": "Test AAA",
    "id": "1234",
    "LineItems": [
        {
            "parent_id": "",
            "productid": "24x34147",
            "sequence-no": "1",
            "quantity": "0.000",
            "listprice": 0.0
        },
        {
            "parent_id": "",
            "productid": "24x34147",
            "sequence-no": "2",
            "quantity": "5.000",
            "listprice": 0.0
        }
    ]
}]
```

I am trying to delete the dictionary/dictionaries inside of the LineItems which have quantity = "0.000" and save the other data as it is in the same format. Following is my code and what I have tried. It is printing an empty list.

```
        with open("examplejson.json", 'r') as f:
                data = json.loads(f.read())            
        
        for element in data:
                service_id = element["LineItems"]
                for i, el in enumerate(service_id):
                    # print(service_id[i]["quantity"])
                    a = [item for item in el if service_id[i]["quantity"] == "0.000"]
                    print(a)
```

Comment: This looks really complicated for a Python beginner. You know `del d[key]`? for deleting a dict entry?

Comment: My question is about deleting a whole dictionary with the condition on its key "quantity", I don't want to delete just dict entry but the whole dictionary.

Comment: I worked on the answer. Consider it for the green check as it is better than the other answer, which makes a new copy instead of addressing your goal of deleting.

Comment: Give the green check to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wo = [{
"subject": "Test AAA",
"id": "1234",
"LineItems": [
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "productid": "24x34147",
        "sequence-no": "1",
        "quantity": "0.000",
        "listprice": 0.0
    },
    {
        "parent_id": "",
        "productid": "24x34147",
        "sequence-no": "2",
        "quantity": "5.000",
        "listprice": 0.0
    }
]
```

}]

```
l = len(wo[0]['LineItems'])
for zz in range(l):
    z = l - zz -1
    if wo[0]['LineItems'][z]['quantity'] == "0.000":
        del wo[0]['LineItems'][z]
```

Iterates through the list backwards and deletes the "0.000" entries. It counts backwards to avoid out of range errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each element, and pull out all LineItems where quantity is not 0.

```
for element in data:
    storage = []
    for el in element["LineItems"]:
        if float(el['quantity']) != 0:
            storage.append(el)
    element['LineItems'] = storage
```

I'm converting the quantity to a float, then comparing it to 0 - that way, you catch quantity == 0, or 0.0, or 0.000000, etc.